# Combining .txt files to create a one pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, automation, text-editors

I have around 200 .txt files. All files are named in order Chapter 1 to 200. How I can create single pdf book by combining all txt files with Chapters Indexed and starting every new chapter on new page with Heading Chapter Number. Is there any tool which can automate this process? I have Adobe Acrobat but I didn't found any ways to achieve this process. Any help, suggestions i can get?

Answer (score 0):

There is a powershell code which can do that:

```
Set-Location "Filepath"
New-Item "PDF.txt" -Type File
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | ForEach {
  $Content = Get-Content $_.FullName
  $Content >>"PDF.txt"
}
$Content = Get-Content "PDF.txt"
$ExportFormat = 17; $SaveOption = 0
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $False
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Select = $Word.Selection
$Select.TypeText($Content)
$Doc.PageSetup.Orientation = 1
$Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat("PDF.pdf",$ExportFormat);
$Doc.close([ref]$SaveOption);
$Word.Quit()
```

This is based on code from http://blog.tofte-it.dk/powershell-convert-a-text-document-to-a-pdf/. I modified the code as per your need. Replace "Filepath" with the path where the text files are. This will combine all text files and convert them to PDF. You must have Microsoft word installed for this.

Comment: This is what i am setting Get-Content : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The specified wildcard pattern is not valid: 51.
he Interstellar Meteoroid Stream [D.txt
At E:\pdf.ps1:4 char:25
+   $Content = Get-Content <<<<  $_.FullName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand